# JMeter: Perfmon report shows 100% usage of server's CPU but it was only 1.5% on AWS dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am running a load test for 1 million threads through JMeter and want to view the resource utilization on the server. For that, I am using Perfmon plugin. When the report is generated, it shows 100% usage of CPU but when view my AWS server dashboard, CPU utilization was only 1.5% at the maximum point.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Your AWS metrics are going to be averaged over either 1 minute or 5. What happens if you run your test for several minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of incorrect configuration of the [PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/), given the proper configuration it should be precise enough and capture the CPU usage (as well as other metrics) in the real time

Demo:

[image]

For the above demo I used [s-tui](https://pypi.org/project/s-tui/) on AWS side, [sha1sum](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sha1sum.1.html) to stress the CPU and pretty much default configuration of the PerfMon Metrics Collector

More information just in case: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)